# Seaborn distplot not showing proper axis labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, format, seaborn

I have the following numerical dataset, that I convert to some text for easy bucketing in a [`seaborn distplot`:](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html)

```
Counter({0.0: 29076, 227.92: 26401, 473.51: 12045, 195.98: 7500, 495.0: 3750, 53.83: 3750, 385.0: 3750, 97.08: 3750, 119.39: 3750, 118.61: 3750, 30.0: 3750, 13000.0: 3750, 553.22: 3750, 1420.31: 3750, 1683.03: 3750, 1360.48: 3750, 1361.16: 3750, 1486.66: 3750, 1398.5: 3750, 4324.44: 3750, 4500.0: 3750, 1215.51: 3750, 1461.27: 3750, 772.5: 3750, 3330.0: 3750, 915.75: 3750, 2403.1225: 3750, 1119.5: 3750, 2658.13: 3618, 492.0: 1818, 10000.0: 1809, 0.515: 1809, 118.305: 1809, 215.0: 1809, 513.0: 1809, 237.5: 1809, 15452.5: 1809, 377838.0: 1809, 584983.0: 1809, 10772.61: 1809, 883.87: 1809, 110494.0: 1809, 2727.0: 1809, 1767.0: 1809, 4792.5: 1809, 6646.5: 1809, 7323.75: 1809, 4399.5: 1809, 2737.5: 1809, 9088.5: 1809, 6405.0: 1809, 0.36: 1809, 112.055: 1809, 247.5: 1809, 232.5: 1809, 18000.0: 1809, 38315.0: 1809, 8100.0: 1809, 63115.34: 1809, 27551.0: 1809, 6398.58: 1809, 78.0: 1809, 26.0: 1809, 1413.0: 1809, 2230.5: 1809, 604.5: 1809, 4037.25: 1809, 18507.0: 1809, 732.75: 1809, 22665.0: 1809, 12212.25: 1809, 17833.5: 1809, 4177.5: 1809, 1521.0: 1809, 2307.0: 1809, 1873.5: 1809, 1948.5: 1809, 1182.0: 1809, 1473.0: 1695})

import pandas as pd, numpy as np, seaborn as sns, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
costs = df['evals'].to_numpy()
new = []
for c in costs:
    if c >= 0 and c < 100:
        new.append('<$100')
    elif c >= 100 and c < 500:
        new.append('<$500 and >= $100')
    elif c >= 500 and c < 2000:
        new.append('<$500 and >= $2000')
    elif c >= 2000 and c < 5000:
        new.append('<$2000 and >= $500')
    elif c >= 5000 and c < 10000:
        new.append('<$10000 and >= $5000')
    elif c >= 10000 and c < 20000:
        new.append('<$20000 and >= $10000')
    elif c >= 20000 and c < 40000:
        new.append('<$40000 and >= $20000')        
    else:
        new.append('>= $40000')

plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
sns.histplot(data=new, stat='probability', kde=True)
plt.show()
```

The graph displays almost perfect:
[image]

However, I noticed that the "$" signs are missing, and the text looks squeezed, i.e. the numbers are too close together to the `and`, and it is not the way I had it typed into strings that get appended into the list.

How can I format this axis properly so the text appears *just as I set it in the list?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

text between two dollar signs `$text$` is interpreted as [MathText](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/mathtext.html). If you dont want this behavior, you need to escape the dollar signs `\$text\$`

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xticks([0.25,0.75],['$test_1$','\$test_1\$'])
```

[image]